# How to Tell Spring 4.1.4 to use MarshallingHttpMessageConverter instead of the Jaxb2RootElementHttpMessageConverter?

Tags: spring-mvc, jaxb2

How to tell Spring 4.1.4 to use MarshallingHttpMessageConverter instead of the Jaxb2RootElementHttpMessageConverter?  The following code snippet doesn't work because the RequestMappingHandlerAdapter does use message converters declared in configuration; but instead uses default pre-configured message converters.

```
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter" scope="singleton">
    <property name="messageConverters" ref="messageConvertersList"/>
</bean>
```

Thanks,

Tonté

Answer (score 0):

Manually configuring the RequestMappingHandlerAdapter doesn't when the use the

```
<mvc:annotation-driven/>
```

because this configuration tell spring to automatically use pre-configured message converters.  In order to use a manually configured MarshallingHttpMessageConverter, you have to first remove `<mvc:annotation-driven/>` from your configuration, and then manually configure your RequestMappingHandlerAdapter as described above in question, like so:

```
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter">
    <property name="messageConverters" ref="messageConvertersList"/>
</bean>
```

Answer (score 0):

I've found another solution (tested with spring 3.2.2, should work in 4.1.4 as well: http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring/4.1.4.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-config) - put your message convertor into `<mvc:annotation-driven>` tag:

```
<mvc:annotation-driven>
    <mvc:message-converters>
            <bean id="marshallingHttpMessageConverter" class="org.springframework.http.converter.xml.MarshallingHttpMessageConverter">
                <property name="marshaller" ref="marshaller" />
                <property name="unmarshaller" ref="marshaller" />
            </bean>
    </mvc:message-converters>
</mvc:annotation-driven>
```

where

```
<bean id="marshaller" class="org.springframework.oxm.jaxb.Jaxb2Marshaller">
    <property name="schema" value="classpath:/my-schema.xsd" />
    <property name="contextPath" value="my.package.with.generated.classes" />
</bean>
```